# как можно определить какие точки принадлежат какому графику?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Моя программа находит по пересечению контуров и линии сетки точки принадлежащим графикам функции(рисунок подкрепляю). Проблема заключается в том что как можно определить зная координаты точки какому графику принадлежит какая точка? Какой контур принадлежит какому графику я не знаю так как некоторые контуры сливаются воедино либо собраны из других маленьких контуров[image: вот эта картинка что она делает]

Comment: В смысле у вас есть готовая картинка вот такая только?

Comment: Таких картинок много, но они разные и в общем случае я привел в пример эту